# Visual Studio 2008 Publish failed view log

Tags: c#, asp.net

There are no errors or warnings on my VS2008 Web Application Project but when I try to publish, it fails. How can I view the VS2008 publish log?

Comment: have you tried cleaning your solution and rebuilding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the messages generated during a Publish are written to the Output window.  Just enable the Output window (View --> Output or Ctrl+Alt+O) and you can watch the messages both during and after the Publish process.